# Shell scripting help needed

Tags: string, shell, unix

I have a particular date(birthday of a person) stored in a file eg 01/02/1900.
I want to know whether the person age is greater than 20 or not.
I'm using shell scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) with [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (i.e. on all major Linux distributions) you can use [`date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) to convert both dates to a number for comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Arguments: <age-limit> <birth-date>

LIMIT=$(date --date="$1 years ago" +%s)
BIRTH=$(date --date="$2" +%s)

if [[ "$BIRTH" -gt "$LIMIT" ]]; then
    echo "Birth-date less than $1 years ago"
else
    echo "Birth-date at least $1 years ago"
fi
```

Please note that date strings such as `01/02/1900` are ambiguous w.r.t. the month/day order. On my system and locale `date` assumes that the month precedes the day - YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Just a joke, but perhaps you can derive what you need: It reads one date per line from `/path/to/file.txt` and outputs how old that person is and wheater it's younger or older than 20.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read DATE junk; do
    QDATE=$(echo "$DATE" | sed 's#/#%2F#g')
    ANS=$(curl -s "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28now+-+${QDATE}%29+in+years" | grep -Eo '"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? years"')
    AGE=$(echo "$ANS" | sed -r -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ years//g' -e 's/\..+//g')

    if [ -z "$AGE" ]; then
        echo "$DATE: ERROR occured"
        continue
    fi

    if [ $AGE -ge 20 ]; then
        echo "$DATE ($ANS): Person older or equal to 20 years"
    else
        echo "$DATE ($ANS): Person younger than 20 years"
    fi
done < /path/to/file.txt
```

Sample:

```
$ cat /path/to/file.txt
01/01/1900
08/11/1992
09/12/1992
$ bash test.sh 
01/01/1900 ("112.9 years"): Person older or equal to 20 years
08/11/1992 ("20 years"): Person older or equal to 20 years
09/12/1992 ("19.92 years"): Person younger than 20 years
```